# Accessing inherited class variables in PHP

Tags: php, class, inheritance, variables

I have two classes. Looking to be able to grab a variable that is within a global object of a class.

```
Class Order {
    public $number = "1234";
}

Class Business {
    public $order;
    function __construct() {
        global $order;
        $order = new Order();
    }
}

$b = new Business();
echo $b->order->number;
```

In the case above nothing is displayed not even an error.
Ive tried different ways of accessing the variable but have only been successful by making a helper function to make a call like the following:

```
echo $b->getOrder()->number;
```

or

```
$temp = $b->order;
echo $temp->number;
```

Both give the required result of "1234" however I am sure there is a way to do it in 1 line without having to make a getter function.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access class variables you need to use `$this->`

```
Class Order {
    public $number = "1234";
}

Class Business {
    public $order;
    function __construct() {
        $this->order = new Order();
    }
}

$b = new Business;
echo $b->order->number;
```